# Set() as key for Javascript object

Tags: javascript, set

In JavaScript, I try the following:

```js
let set1 = new Set([1]);
let set2 = new Set([2]);
let obj = {};
console.log("obj[set2] gives: ", obj[set2]);
obj[set1] = "Should be set1";

console.log(obj);
console.log("obj[set2] gives: ", obj[set2]);
```

It appears, that instead of treating the Set object as a key, it uses the string "[object Set]" as the key, thus making all Sets identical if used as keys. Why is this the correct behavior? Is there a way to use a Set as the key of an object, so I can look up a value associated with a particular Set? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object keys can only be *strings* (or Symbols, rarely). If you try to assign a key which is not a string, it will be cast to a string before being put onto the object.

See what happens when you try to turn a Set into a string:

```js
let set1 = new Set([1]);
let set2 = new Set([2]);
console.log(
  String(set1),
  String(set2)
);
```

No matter what the set contains, when cast to a string, you get `[object Set]`. So, as expected:

```
obj[set1]           ===  obj[set2]
obj['[object Set]'] ===  obj['[object Set]']
```

If you want to use non-string keys, you should use a Map, whose "keys" can be *any value at all*, and not just strings:

```js
let set1 = new Set([1]);
let set2 = new Set([2]);
const map = new Map();
console.log("obj[set2] gives: ", map.get(set2));
map.set(set1, "Should be set1");
console.log("obj[set2] gives: ", map.get(set2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `obj[set1] = "Should be set1";` is really saying `obj['undefined'] = 'Should be set1';`, then you are testing for another `obj[set2]` where `set2` is undefined *(again cast to a String)*, so you get `'Should be set1'`. If you want to know if a set has something it's `setWhatever.has(value);`.